# using a template for more then 1 page

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, page-template, advanced-custom-fields

I have 3 pages under the same custom post type that I made, and I made a custom field of choose between 3 answers when posting a new post to this custom post type and make it so that each page has the same template but shows the posts according to the custom field I made with ACF.

is there a way to do it without making 3 different templates? the 3 pages are supposed to look the same just the posts are different according to the ACF that I choose. thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are ways to do it.

Comment: You should refer to the ACF documentation for how to use the field values in templates.

Comment: I know how to show the posts according to the ACF but I couldn't find how to use the same template for it

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the [WordPress template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) provide a range of templates files to use.

In this case, you should look at the `single-$post-type.php` file. $post-type being your custom post type slug.

Include your template code, including ACF `get_field` calls, and the pages will look the same, but use the content from each post.

Comment: That wasn't the question. They were asking about showing something different based on an ACF field.